# Tools and methods for getting feedback and building community around open source projects

Tags: community, etiquette

Hello Open Source StackExchange!

I am an open source developer looking to understand how to best get feedback on my open source projects. I am trying to choose effective and easy-to-use tools such that users will be able to easily engage with my project.

I see that most (if not all) projects use GitHub, and that many also use slack, discord, mailing lists and other methods of managing feedback and contributions to the project. Therefore, I wonder:

- How did you decide the methods you would use to get feedback?
- What has your experience with those tools been like?
- Finally, what motivates you to contribute to an open source community/ project?

Comment: I recommend you take a look at [this question](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/54/458) and its answers.  They're about attracting contributors, but nearly all of the advice is about building a community, since that's a necessary pre-requisite.